# Conditional tag to check if 'page.php' is being used?

Tags: pages, page-template, conditional-tags

I'm trying to check whether the page.php template is being used or not. I've tried `is_page_template( 'page.php' )` but it doesn't work.

I also can't use `is_page()` because I only want to do something when `page.php` is used, and not when some other custom Page template is used.

Please let me know about this and thanks!

**Edit:** Should have mentioned earlier that I have a file called `common-options.php` which is getting included in almost all the templates (like `index.php`, `page.php`, `single.php` and `page_blog.php`), in this file I'm trying to do the check with the following code:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'page.php' ) ) {
    echo "success!";
}
```

But it's not working when I open a page that is using the "Default Template".

Comment: is_page_template() is the correct function but you say it "doesn't work".  Are you checking inside the loop?

Comment: Hi, I'm checking it in a file which I'm including (using 'include()') at the top of page.php and other files. Please see the edit of my question.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to answer my own question from your edit. Too many possibilities without seeing more of your code. If you are testing the condition inside of the loop, `is_page_template` will not work.  My recommendation is to find out which template is being use and then track down why.   This function will display the current template file on every page to a logged in admin. http://pastebin.com/wkNv9Eug.  Stick this in your functions.php and reload the page.  As long as your theme calls wp_head() you should see the template at the top of every page when logged in.

Comment: The most important question here is: are you checking inside the loop? Are you calling `the_post` in your template file before calling `is_page_template`? (`is_page_template( 'page.php'` won't work either way, but this is still an important question in answering your original question)

Answer (score 12):

I actually ran into the same problem myself and my solution was this code:

```
if(basename(get_page_template()) === 'page.php'){

}
```

`basename(get_page_template())` gets the filename of the page template (according to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template) and we then check if it is equal to `'page.php'`

Comment: May you please elaborate more on how this code will work?

Comment: I agree, this is a solid solution but could be expanded upon.+1

Comment: At least for me, this return true for any page, even if use a custom template (different than page.php)

Comment: This is awesome because it works even if the page is using its default template.

Comment: Works wonderful for me in functions.php with wp enqueue hook. is_page_template( 'page.php' ) didn't fire ... . Wonder if someone would find an explaination ...

Answer (score 7):

You have two useful functions: [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) and [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/).

The `is_page()` function will return `true` when you're on a page, and the `is_page_template()` function will return `false` if the current post (can be a page) is not using a custom template.

So, you just need to use both of these functions together:

```
if ( is_page() && !is_page_template() ) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: This is the most robust answer I think.

Comment: Still works perfect as of this date. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but an interesting one.

In general it is uncommon to check for *template* in WordPress. The template is *result* of main query running and setting up context of request.

If necessary I would probably somehow set a flag at start of `page.php`, such as declaring constant for it, to have my own context for that.

Overall though it makes me think that any logic that requires such move should be considered to be adjusted in line with more common mechanics and conditionals.

Comment: +1 Any code needing this condition could probably just be placed unconditionally within page.php

Comment: I disagree. For me, I am trying to enqueue a JS script only on the default page.php, inside of functions.php. Why make the user load it on any other page if they don't need to? I do think there are use cases for this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is very simple. Just use:

is_page_template()

If it returns true than page.php is not being used and vice versa
:)

Comment: Wouldn't this return false on post pages, though?

Answer (score 0):

```
$bulkitnt_custom_page_control = is_page_template( 'custom-page.php' );

    if( $bulkitnt_custom_page_control != true ){
        do_action('bulkitnt_header_action');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in the seachbar.php

basename(get_page_template()) === ( 'page.php' )

This my compleet code:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'tpl-ads-home.php' ) || basename(get_page_template()) === ( 'page.php' ) || is_page_template( 'tpl-refine-search.php' ) || is_page_template( 'tpl-categories.php' ) || is_search() || is_404() || is_tax( APP_TAX_CAT ) || is_tax( APP_TAX_TAG ) || is_singular( APP_POST_TYPE ) ) :

    $args = cp_get_dropdown_categories_search_args( 'bar' );
```

Comment: Compleet code

<?php
if ( is_page_template( 'tpl-ads-home.php' ) || basename(get_page_template()) === ( 'page.php' ) || is_page_template( 'tpl-refine-search.php' ) || is_page_template( 'tpl-categories.php' ) || is_search() || is_404() || is_tax( APP_TAX_CAT ) || is_tax( APP_TAX_TAG ) || is_singular( APP_POST_TYPE ) ) :

 $args = cp_get_dropdown_categories_search_args( 'bar' );
?>

Comment: You should add your code to your answer, not as a comment

Answer (score -2):

Just use null array instead of 'page.php'
eg: `is_page_template(array(''));`

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: You could also provide an example.