# What does is_page_template() compare against?

Tags: page-template, codex

Looking through the [Wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/), it says that `is_page_template()` compares against a "template name", if one is provided.

I have a template stored in `page-homepage.php` called `Homepage`:

```
/*
 * Template Name: Homepage
 * Description: The template for displaying the homepage
 */
```

And I have some code I wish to run in my functions.php when I'm using that template:

```
if (is_page_template('Homepage')) { 
   ...
```

But it isn't being triggered when I'm on a page which uses that template.

When I look at the code that Wordpress executes for `is_page_template()`, it looks like it actually checks for the document name, not the template name...?

```
function is_page_template( $template = '' ) {

    $page_template = get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() );

    if ( $template == $page_template )
        return true;
```

In my instance it seems that `$page_template` is `page-homepage.php` --  not the template name, like the documentation suggests...?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Good observation regarding the documentation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your condition should be written like this:

```
if (is_page_template('path/file.php')) { 
    // Do stuff
}
```

I believe the confusion is a result of two things:

1. The docs refer to "name" ambiguously.  Specifying "file name" would make the documentation much more clear.
2. The code behind `is_page_template()` shows the `get_page_template_slug()` function at its core.  This function actually returns a file name, not the template slug.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template_slug

When specifying an argument for the `is_page_template()` function (as in the example above), the file path is relative to the theme root.

This function will not work inside the loop.

EDIT: an important issue to note here as well.  The `is_page_template()` function will return empty/false if the page is using the default template from the hierarchy.  If a custom template is not assigned, you must use another method, such as `basename(get_page_template())`.  See Jacob's answer here for more details:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/328427/45202

Comment: It would be nice to have an explanation what *path* stands for here.

Comment: Added additional clarification and details on why this can be confusing.

Comment: Wow. A double whammy of confusion. I can understand the docs being a bit ambiguous (although it really should be fixed), but I'm really surprised that `get_page_template_slug()` doesn't actually return a slug!

Comment: Agreed. Lending further support to the notion that "naming things" is one of the hardest things when writing code.

Comment: This answer contains the "best practice" solution. However, if your page is using the "default template" (but it is actually a Page Template), [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239950/10388) may interest you.

Comment: Thank you, @rinogo.  Added a note above as I just ran into this issue, personally, again.

Answer (score 8):

I think the best thing to say is, it checks on the FILE name and in your case it would be page-homepage.php. so:

```
if (is_page_template('page-homepage.php')) { 
  ...
```

Other things to think of is if the template file is actually stored within another folder inside the theme.  [read more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/#more-information)

One more thing, the `Template Name: Homepage` is genrally whats used to identify the template when creating a page or post.

Comment: As another answer points out - it also takes path into consideration. `page-templates/page-homepage.php` is different than the template in the theme root.

Comment: Interesting and something I didnt know, just to confirm, I can store the page templates outside the theme or child theme folder?

Comment: FYI this one works also on Sage development environment