# is_page_template not working

Tags: page-template

Hi trying this code below to get working, but no look so far.
Idea is simple if page template is **page-47.php** display `<h1>Something</h1>` else `<h1>This will show on any other page</h1>` .

```
<?php if ( is_page_template( 'page-47.php' ) ): ?>

   <h1>Something</h1>

<?php else: ?>

   <h1>This will show on any other page</h1>

<?php endif ?>
```

Thank You

Comment: Where do you use this code?

Comment: is `page-47.php` in directory ? Not in the theme root. If so you need to `is_page_template( 'templates/page-47.php' );`

Comment: Hi page-47.php is inside main theme folder. So i using `is_page_template( 'page-47.php' )`. But not working.

Comment: @DeividasKrupstas - is `47` the page ID? It should be the slug/name.

Comment: @ Liam Stewart  `page-47.php` this is page template.

Comment: As Kryzsiek asked - what file is this code actually in? You may be trying to call it somewhere before the query is fully set up.

Comment: @WebElaine So for example if use code inside  `page-47.php`. Code outputs `This will show on any other page`  but i need `<h1>Something</h1>`.

Comment: But why would you have this code running in `page-47.php` at all? That page is specific to the page with ID 47, so you can just include the `<h1>` tag you want there with no conditional.

Comment: @@WebElaine Hi,if i put the same code in the footer so by logic should if page template is page-47.php display <h1>Something</h1> else <h1>This will show on any other page</h1>. Yes i understand i can just put in page-47.php <h1>Something</h1> and in rest of templates <h1>This will show on any other page</h1>. I just want to undertend why code is not working.

Comment: Since this is a stable function that is known to work, there is something in the **context** of how you are using it that is off. That is why people are asking where exactly you are using it. For instance, if you have written a custom loop on the page and you are using this function within that loop, your results will be different.

Comment: @DeividasKrupstas there's some confusion going on here, and some missing information and context. Please edit your question to fill in the missing gaps, e.g. which file is the code in your question in ( where are you calling `is_page_template from is important information ), as well as where on your site ( is it a page? an archive? a post? it isn't clear ). Make sure your question contains all the information, information in the comments gets lost

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`is_page_template()` will only tell you if the page is using a *custom* page template. Meaning a template that was created by adding the `Template Name:` comment to the file and selecting it from the Template dropdown, as described [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use). The function works by checking the post meta for which template was selected.

If you have created a page template using the slug or ID using the method described [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page), which you appear to have, then the template being used is not stored in meta, so won't be picked up by the `is_page_template()` function.

If you want to know the filename of the current template being used, regardless of whether it's a custom template or not, you can use the global `$template` variable:

```
global $template;

if ( basename( $template ) === 'page-47.php' ) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation!. How can adapt your suggested code in my example?      `<?php 
global $template;
if ( is_page_template( 'page-47.php' ) ) {
 echo "Hello world!"; 
} else {
   
}
?>`

Comment: My answer includes your example...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jacob Peattie! This also solved my problem.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_currency_symbol', 10, 2 );

function change_currency_symbol( $symbols, $currency ) {
    
    global $template;
    
    if ( basename( $template ) === 'archive-chiptuning.php' && ( 'EUR' === $currency )) {
        return '';
    }
        return $symbols;
}
```